# Run C# Application after installation

Tags: c#, visual-studio, installation

I have an application in C# that I want to execute after the installation process ends. Can I override any function in the installation class? It's not a service, it's a windows form application.

Thank you

Comment: Which installer are you using?

Comment: We need more information on what you're using to make your installation program.